# human readable schedule syntax like functionality in my app?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, antlr, human-readable

cron in google app engine have human readable syntax for cron job scheduling.

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/cron#The_Schedule_Format

How do I implement similar functionality in my application, where use enter schedule in human
readable format and program parse and store the actual value ?

edit:
I think they are using antlr3 library, But I could not able to figure out how they are using it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, in this instance there are two spots you need to look into.

First antlr is what gives you your parser to parse the english/human readable formats into your program as a stream of tokens. From this string you will then determine the meaning such as:

```
run backup every 2 days
```

which would turn into a stream of tokens such as:

```
<command_type> := run
<command_to_run> := backup
<time_frame_times> := every
<digit> := 2
<time_frame_modifier> := days
```

From here you will then determine the meaning of the sentence using some kind of state machine that could be written (simplified form) as:

```
if token == command_type:
    switch( token.val )
        case "run":
            state = run
            program = tokens.pop().val
if token == time_frame_times:
    switch( token.val )
        case "every":
            time_frame_state = repeat_indefinitely
if token == time_frame_modifier:
    switch( token.val )
        case "days":
            time_frame_modifier = every_N_days
if token == digit:
    switch( time_Frame_modifier )
        case every_N_days:
            time_frame_modifier_value = token.val
```

Something like that would suffice to parse the string into your required values.

The second part would be to connect this into `cron` itself or write your own scheduler within your program itself which I think is more along the lines of your use case.

Antlr Python: http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/ANTLR3/Python+runtime